# What is the origin of giving “Pesicho” to the expectant husband?

Tags: minhag, synagogue, pregnancy-birth, opening-the-ark, gabbai

What is the origin of the practice of giving *“pesicho”* (the honor of opening the Ark) to the husband whose wife is expecting a baby?

Comment: I recall it is a Chida, but don't know a source.

Comment: It's supposed to be a segulah to have children, but public segulot in some places are only given to people who the outcome is virtually certain.  Other places I have seen give 'p'ticha' to childless husbands who hope to one day have children.

Comment: For those that will have difficlty understanding (I had to re-read this several times), the reference is to *"p'ticha"*....

Comment: I remember once hearing that the removal of the Torah from the Ark is supposed to parallel removing the fetus from the womb. I have absolutely no source to support this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the back of the [Chumash Shai LeMorah](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?main_page=product_sefer_info&products_id=496&zenid=oa92mmulln43r8r6hfn115ejp6), a list and hierarchy of the the people who are obligated to receive an Aliyah to the Torah. He adds parenthetically as follows:

> It is written in the Sefer Avodat Hakodesh of the Chida Z"l that there is a custom in Eretz Yisroel that someone whose wife enters her 9th month of pregnancy should be careful to do the Mitzvah of Opening the Ark. This is a nice custom and has Kabbalistic support.

Here is a [link to the Chida (Mareh B'Etzbah 3:90)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41865&pgnum=16).

["Pesicha During Pregnancy"](http://www.schneersoncenter.org/page.asp?pageID=%7B56F73177-782C-4F25-8F70-A6DC14F11327%7D&displayAll=1), by Rabbi Yossi Braun, extensively covers this topic and brings many places that discuss it. (Thanks to [Uri Cohen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15929/uri-cohen) for the updated link.)

Comment: I just want to point out, that the Chida is not the origin of the custom. The Chida is reporting a custom that exists in Israel during his time.

Answer (score 4):

From an article ["Pesicha During Pregnancy", by Rabbi Yossi Braun](http://www.congregationlubavitch.org/page.asp?pageID=%7B56F73177-782C-4F25-8F70-A6DC14F11327%7D&displayAll=1):

> The Birchas Ephraim 60 (This is a pamphlet that is printed as an
>   addendum to Pischei Sh'earim, Talmudic novellae by Rabbi Yisachar of
>   Tchenstechow - Bilgurei 5660). says as follows: "My children, do not
>   forget to introduce the tradition from our master, **the Rashba**, in
>   whose name I have found recorded, that one should accustom himself
>   that when his wife is pregnant he take the honor of opening the ark
>   from the seventh month onwards during the recitation of the liturgical
>   poem An'im zemiros. At this stage he should recite a prayer in
>   accordance with what G-d will place in his mouth".

Based on this the custom dates back to the 13th century - although it
is only mentioned for Anim Zemiros.

Comment: Is [this](http://thetorahcenter.com/page.asp?pageID={56F73177-782C-4F25-8F70-A6DC14F11327}&displayAll=1) your source? If so, you should cite it.

Comment: I am citing it, although I have copied it from a Parsha sheet that a local individual gives out in my town.